# Is there any way to validate array in firestore rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When i see my data in firebase console it will look like below

[image]

I am writing firestore security rules to protect data.

security rules:

```
     match /wallpost/{wallpostId} {
          allow read: if true;
          allow list: if request.query.limit <= 10;
          allow create, update, delete: if resource.data.createdBy == request.auth.uid && request.resource.data.createdBy is string && request.resource.data.description is string 
// && **HERE I WANT VALIDATE TAG - WHICH IS A ARRAY OF STRING** 
        }
```

Could anyone knows how to validate array of data in firestore.

(My Mind: If we cant validate array in firestore, anyone can inject huge junk data and hack firestore also. So we should not allow the user to write the array or object directly, instead use firestore function to do this mapping and arrange data in correct place)

Please help me...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allow reading the document if `tag1` is in the `tag` field, you can do:

```
match /posts/{postID} {
  allow read: if 'tag1' in resource.data.tag
}
```

Also see:

- the blog post [Better Arrays in Cloud Firestore!](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html), which contains this handy diagram:

[image]

Comment: The same logic would apply there. If you want to validate in the document that is being written (instead of the document as it exists before the write), use `request.resource` instead of just `resource`.

Comment: use can update like update( {viewers: [1, 2, 3, NaN, null]}, {merge: true} ).

How do i restrict this user using firebase rules. please suggest. because firestore dont have for loop also...

Comment: it would be helpful, if you could explain with example... i am new to firestore....

Comment: Could you please confirm, Whether it is possible to write security rules or not... So that i will go with some other options...

Comment: My answer shows how to validate that a certain tag is present. If that's not what you want, I don't understand *what* you're trying to validate about the array of tags.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to loop over the values in an array field in security rules.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I looked all over but failed to find how to validate field types. For example,  "request.resource.data.tags is array" -is this a valid condition? or should it be "is list", or "is List"?

Comment: This is how I recently tested for an array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56403487/check-if-request-resource-data-is-a-list-of-strings-in-firebase-firestore/56403753#56403753