# Check if request.resource.data is a list of strings in Firebase Firestore

Tags: list, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

How do I check if a field is of type `string[]` in firestore rules?

I have a `tags` field in a document, which should be a list of strings, and I want to enforce that. Normally, I can say `request.resource.data is int` if I want to see if the field is an `int`, but I can't find an equivalent for `lists`.

Thanks!

Comment: Please file a feature request for checking the types of items in a list.  You are not the first person to ask for this, and the rules team needs to understand how frequently this comes up.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: What you can do instead is use a Cloud Functions trigger to look at the contents of the document and check the types of everything that got stored.  Then if something is invalid, you can delete the document, correct its contents (e.g. convert strings to ints) or somehow mark it invalid so it's not being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit type check in the rules language (at least as far as I know). So the best I can come up with is trying to find a way to distinguish between a [`List`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List) (the type of an array), and other types.

For example, a list has a `join()` method, which can be used to concatenate the values from the list into a single string. Since (as far as I can see) none of the other types have that operation, this check can detect an array:

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.categories.join(",") != "";
```

Any non-empty array will pass this test, while empty arrays and other types will fail. In the simulator this gives a pretty ugly error message, but that translates to a normal, generic "permission denied" when exposed to clients.

For my own future reference: test code is [here](https://jsbin.com/xuviyel/edit?html,js,console).

Comment: Should you typecheck the list first to save the ugly error? `allow write: if request.resource.data.categories is list`

Answer (score 0):

```
allow create if request.resource.data.nameOfYourTag is list
```

will accept arrays of strings or numbers, both empty and non-empty arrays will pass. Just tested it today.